# Can a country borrow an expert from another country and make him in charge of a ministry?

Tags: economy, cabinet

Suppose, a country is facing deep-rooted economic mismanagement and has billions of dollars of external debts. The prime minister/president tried several local experts, both elected and technocrat, but they failed to deliver as expected.

The PM/president knows a country where a guy (say, [Alexei Kudrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Kudrin) of Russia) became famous for single-handedly lifting a country's economy. He wants to put this guy in charge of the economy.

Can the PM/president borrow an expert from another country and put him in charge of a ministry?

Comment: If the person and/or country agrees I don’t see why not.

Comment: This would be better suited to the Law SE.

Comment: To be "in charge of a ministry" implies [cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(government)).

Comment: It depends on the country and its constitution.  If you have a specific country in mind, please tag it in your question.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII This question seems to be just fine for politics as it centers around who can serve in a government. Also if you think that it is better on another site you probably shouldn't answer it on this site.

Comment: In many countries, a close adviser to the president/head of government might have more impact than a cabinet minister. That or even an advisory position outside of government would be a more natural fit for an outside expert like that.

Comment: In most cases, a country cannot prevent one of its nationals from being hired by a foreign government, unless there is some well founded reasons (for example that person has had access to his country confidential information the secrets laws of that country restrict their activities).

Comment: @JoeW I cover my bases.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII Voting to close a question and answering it don't make sense you should do one or the other not both.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps. It wouldn't happen. The informal norms in favor of appointing only politicians as ministers is a strong one across these systems. They'd make someone like that an appointee or a consultant, rather than a minister. [Milton Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_Friedman#Visit_to_Chile) did something similar once in Chile.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend entirely on the law of the land in the given country.  In the United States, for example, you can't serve in Congress or the Senate (our analog to a parliament) unless you've been a Citizen for 7+ years.

What's far more likely is that such outside experts are likely to be hired in a consulting role, or appointed to senior positions of certain institutions rather than a ministry itself.

Comment: Of course, in the U.S., ministers (i.e. executive branch department heads and their senior deputies) are not members of Congress. Congress is not our analog to parliament in this regard. The U.S. equivalent of "minsiters" are appointed by the President with Senate ratification and while they must swear an oath of office to the U.S. that could void a foreign citizenship in some cases, there is no residency requirement to be, for example, Secretary of Treasury.

Comment: Fair cop. I was mostly reaching for the example of what a disqualification would look like, there.  The honest answer to a question like this is "It depends."

Comment: Perhaps the closest analogy would be whether a foriegner could be appointed as a cabinet member. There may be nothing legally preventing it, but it's politically unlikely. The Senate would never approve them.

Answer (score 1):

As William Walker III pointed out in his answer, that depends very much on the laws of the country. Let me add some individual data points:

- In the EU, citizens of other EU countries *can* run for [certain elective public offices](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:31994L0080&from=DE) if they meet residency requirements. But then, the EU is more than just a free trade area.
- To complicate things, cabinet-level appointments are not elective offices. In Germany, the citizenship requirement for cabinet officials seems to be not *quite* clear, but the [assumption](https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/817830/7cbcca44817f6224df68d1263c152524/WD-3-262-20-pdf-data.pdf) is that they must be qualified to stand for elections.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good example is [the Cioloş cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciolo%C8%99_Cabinet) which was arguably entirely made out of technocrats.

A few of the members were working abroad (e.g. European Commission-related jobs) before accepting a ministry position, so technically speaking they came from another country to assume office.